# send iPhone current location at a particular time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkmapview

I want to write a program that sends GPS location (lattitude, longitude) at a particular time... so it's like an alarm, but it's not buzzing, instead of sending locations at a particular time.

The best way I can think of it is by push notifications from the server, but this would be useless

**UPDATE:**

I actually wanna create something similar to [this](http://techcrunch.com/2010/08/02/future-checkin/), automatic checkin. If this app can be done then what I wanna do is easy, I just check the time, if it fits checkin if not pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is not practically possible. Unless you use a method to keep your app active in the foreground all of the time, the alarm time will pass and your app will not be activating to run any code. Push notifications from a server are allowed to play sounds, display messages or change your app's badge number, but they do not run code in your app. Background execution is limited to 10 minutes of runtime, after which the OS will kill your app.

Comment: so what's the best thing that is possible? ask the user to turn the gps manually at time x?

Comment: @MacTeo's answer is essentially correct, but battery life is going to be quite bad, especially if you set the accuracy high enough that it turns on the GPS radio.

Comment: I am just curious in that app on the video, is that app basically having the GPS on all the time

Comment: On iPhone 4, you can set up regions that will trigger when you enter or leave them. He might have used that for favorites. On 3GS and later, you can also use significant location change triggers, but this is based on cell towers and is coarse-grained (around 2 km). You'll note his slider for accuracy states it's a trade-off between location accuracy and battery life. That likely maps to the `CLLocation` accuracy, which in turn dictates what hardware is used. He says it periodically checks, so in the meantime it likely stops monitoring, which will help with power consumption.

Comment: By set up regions, you mean we can code a particular region (lattitude, longitude) and when the phone hits that region it checks in?

Comment: Theoretically, yes, but it only works on the iPhone 4 and I don't know how small the region can get. Read up on [Monitoring Shape-Based Regions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW13).

Comment: No, iPhone 4. It's a hardware thing. I know it doesn't work on iPhone 3GS and earlier. I'm not sure about iPad models.

Answer (score 1):

You can let run application in background forever if it uses at least one of this service: GPS, Voip or Music. For any other app the 10 minutes limit will kill them.

Put this in your application .plist file

```
  <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
            <string>location</string>
    </array>
```

Comment: so in the video I mentioned above... the application uses this method? it has the gps on all the time

Comment: You can try to save battery life using the CLLocationManager's methods desiredAccuracy, distanceFilter and even the startMonitoringForRegion:desiredAccuracy: if you need exactly the same behavior shown in the video. In some devices you can even use the startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges to avoid GPS and use just cellular network cell.